# Facebook edge.create doesn't fire if the like button has a confirm dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to create a page that requires visitors to 'Like' a Facebook Page before showing all the content.

The page with the like button is hosted on herokuapp.com but the URL to like is a Facebook page (ie. the host URL and the 'Like' URL are different).

I've successfully included a like button and I have subscribed to the edge.create event, and everything was working fine (I could write to console.log or run custom javascript) when clicking on the Like button.

However in the course of testing I've clicked Like/Unlike so many times that my site has now been flagged as potential clickjacking and the Like button now changes to 'Confirm' and asks the user to go through the Confirm dialog process.

I understand that I just need to accumulate more 'white' Likes and this dialog will go away eventually, but in the meantime it's causing me problems.

Basically, when I go through the 'Confirm' process in Google Chrome or on my iPhone, the 'Confirm' link never changes to 'Liked', the number of likes doesn't change and the edge.create event doesn't fire.

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour? I've read just about every post on Stack Overflow relating to either the Confirm process and edge.create but no one seems to have had this particular problem.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: I have ran into this before, unfortunately you have to wait the 24 / 72 (to when ever Facebook feels like unlocking) hour span for the confirm dialog to go away or get more white likes another way. edge.create will not fire.   I would suggest making a dumby app for testing likes in that manner, then switching to real app when you are ready for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by moving my app to be hosted my own domain instead of heroku, even though I was liking the same page. Not an ideal solution for everyone but it worked for me. In future I will create dummy apps and pages to test this process out.